# Gunicorn on Top of Flask (Critical Section)

Tags: python, gunicorn

When I put gunicorn in front of a Flask service that has a method like:

```
@app.route('/testr/', methods=['POST'])
def test():
  atomic_section_here
```

To my understanding, I can create multiple workers (lets say 5). Does this mean that I get 5 processes each with their own interpreter? Or do I get 5 processes spawned by one interpreter using `multiprocessing`?

If I want the critical section to be atomic, can I just initialize a lock at the top-level of this file and acquire it within the critical section?

Answer (score 2):

You get 5 processes spawned via `multiprocessing` from 1 interpreter. You can share a lock between workers with `mutltiprocessing.Lock().aquire` in your route and `preload_app = True` in gunicorn.conf.

[Here is some reading about the design of Gunicorn, including the workers.](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/design.html)

[Here is a relevant question and answer about sharing the lock.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213619/sharing-a-lock-between-gunicorn-workers)